# Is there a difference in scala type bound notation direction?

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance, generic-variance

Is there a difference in scala type bound notation direction, as in is `[B <: A]` the same as `[A >: B]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B <: A` means that `B` has an *upper-bound* of `A`. Which means that `B` can be any type from `Nothing` to `A` in the type hierarchy.

`A >: B` means that `A` has a *lower-bound* of `B`, which means that `A` can be anything from `B` to `Any` in the type hierarchy.

In general, they do not mean the same thing. Each one imposes a bound on a different type parameter. This isn't variance notation either, these are type bounds.

Comment: Like `super` vs `extends` in Java iirc when dealing with type signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Here `[B <: A]` you declare type `B` which extends `A`,
here `[A >: B]` you declare type `A` which is a parent of type `B`.